# Is it a good Idea to use RESTfull api so as to create a web service that deals with interacting with API of another website?

Tags: jsp, restlet

I want to create  a website in JSP where I have to deal with the API of another website which sends XML data when called . Is it a good idea to use RESTfull api ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a bridge between the other web site and your users?

The other website has published it's API and you have no choice if that is RESTful or not. You are forced to consume there web services as they are. You can consume those (possibly non-RESTful) services and then expose RESTful services to your clients.

If you are asking are RESTful services good...that is a design dependent decision. Some will say that is how the web was meant to be and yes you should absolutely expose RESTful services. Most will be a bit more pragmatic and will say it depends.

Can you provide any more information?

Comment: yes I can . What I am developing is a site that deals with API of another website . The only thing mentioned in that website is that the API returns XML data . I am a NOOB in JSP , and am forced to code in it . So been blindly asking questions to get some answers how to do it .

Comment: Is it a public site? If yes, please provide the URL. Otherwise, sites that expose webservices generally provide some information about the format of the calls to the service and the format of the data from the service. Sounds like you know it is returning XML. Many web sites exposing web services provide a WSDL file that can be used to automatically generate a proxy (class you can use in your code to communicate with the web services). This would be ideal. Then you can use something like this http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html. Otherwise, you have to hand roll your proxy and objects.

Comment: This doesn't look too bad. No WSDL, but the api is provided in that document. You will need to construct the URL for their site using parameters provided to you from your JSP page. Your server will request the constructed URL and be returned a blob of XML data that you will need to parse. If I were doing this I would start by creating a command line app that does the requesting and get a hold of those xml blobs. Once you have a couple of xml blobs, start writing your parsing engine. Then wrap the JSP ui layer on top. Sorry for the lack of details.

Comment: A few doubts if I may ask . As its a jsp page , this command line app that you are talking about is a servlet right ? Can you give me a an example couple of lines of code to work on it . I will be very thankful . I am grateful nonetheless for the help till now

Comment: I just want to know how does the request , response mechanism work in JSP . I am decent in PHP , but JSP is absolutely murdering me here .

Comment: If I were doing this, I would create a console app that consumed the web service and parsed the result first. I would leave the web server out of the equation at first. I am thinking two classes. One that is responsible for fetching the raw XML given the URL. The other that parses the raw XML and returns a typed object. Only after those two pieces are solid, would I take those classes and begin using them in my web application. I need to go offline for a bit. I will check back later.